# Do GHC REWRITE pragmas have to be type preserving?

Tags: haskell, ghc, pragma

```
import Data.Void (Void,absurd)
```

Say I have a small term language:

```
data Term c v where
  Var :: v               -> Term c v
  Con :: c -> [Term c v] -> Term c v
```

If I want to combine terms of the type `Term c Void` and `Term c Int`, that should be possible, since I have the guarantee that the first term does not contain any variables. Therefore, I can write the function:

```
castVar :: Term c Void -> Term c v
castVar (Var i   ) = absurd i
castVar (Con x xs) = Con x (map castVar xs)
```

However, it'd be a shame to actually run this function, since I know for a fact that it doesn't actually change anything. Is it safe to add the following pragmas:

```
{-# NOINLINE castVar #-}
{-# RULES "castVar/id" forall x. castVar x = x; #-}
```

And will this actually achieve the desired result?

Are there better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this wouldn't work. Rewrite rules are only applied if the types check. In this case the rule would only fire if you ran `castVar :: Term c Void -> Term c Void`, which isn't very helpful. (See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html for more info on rewrite rules)

What you want is to coerce the type. It's safe to do this because you know there's no `Void` in the `Term`. You could either do this by importing `Unsafe.Coerce` and `castVar = unsafeCoerce` or make `Term` an instance of `Functor` (you can derive it for this simple version) and use `unsafeVacuous` from `Data.Void.Unsafe`.